# Knockoutjs Dynamic Template Binding with Foreach and AfterAdd

Tags: javascript, templates, dynamic, binding, knockout.js

What I want to do is Dynamic Template binding to an observableArray with the options to specify "afterAdd" and "beforeRemove". It's probably easier to understand by looking at my code:

```
<div id="form_container" data-bind="template: {name: fnGetTemplate,
                                               foreach: OpenedForms(),
                                               beforeRemove: fnBeforeRemoveProcess(),
                                               afterAdd: fnAfterAddProcess()}"></div>
```

(simplfied version) OpenedForms = ko.observableArray()[{Template: 'Template1'}, {Template: 'Template2}];

fnGetTemplate pretty much take in the array element and return the template name, e.g "Template1".

Everything within the array get rendered; however, the problem is that **fnAfterAddProcess**//**fnBeforeRemoveProcess** get called before **fnGetTemplate**. So it's actually rendering the template after calling afterAdd and afterRemove. I tried replacing afterAdd with afterRender, but the same thing happened. For some reason it actually called **fnBeforeRemoveProcess** -> **fnAfterAddProcess** -> **fnGetTemplate** when I only added an element to the observableArray.

However, this worked correctly, except it doesn't support "beforeRemove":

```
<div id="form_container" data-bind="foreach: {data: OpenedForms, afterRender: AfterAddProcess}">
    <div data-bind="template: {name: Template, data: $data}"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe I would need to write a custom binding, but if someone could point where I went wrong or perhaps a better way to tackle the problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> however, the problem is that fnAfterAddProcess//fnBeforeRemoveProcess get called before fnGetTemplate

That's because you're calling the functions in your binding, so they are run when the binding string is parsed. You need to pass just a reference to the function in your binding:

```
<div id="form_container" data-bind="template: {name: fnGetTemplate,
                                               foreach: OpenedForms(),
                                               beforeRemove: fnBeforeRemoveProcess,
                                               afterAdd: fnAfterAddProcess}"></div>
```